# relationship between section and entry in CDA documents

Tags: xml, cdata, hl7, cda

My question is if the **entry/clinical statement** in CDA document is identifiable by the parent **section**. I have come across a situation where I need to identify which entry belongs to the section. For example the section below

```
<section>
                    <!-- conforms to Vital Signs section with entries optional -->
                    <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.2.4"/>
                    <!-- Vital Signs section with entries required -->
                    <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.2.4.1"/>
                    <code code="8716-3" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1"
                        codeSystemName="LOINC" displayName="Vital Signs"/>
```

Is this section related to which of the first entry or the second entry below?

**First entry**

```
<entry typeCode="DRIV">
                                <organizer classCode="CLUSTER" moodCode="EVN">
                                    <!-- ** Vital signs organizer ** -->
                                    <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.4.26"/>
                                    <id root="c6f88320-67ad-11db-bd13-0800200c9a66"/>
                                    <code xsi:type="CD" code="46680005" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.96"
                                    codeSystemName="SNOMED-CT" displayName="Vital signs"/>
```

**Second entry**

```
<entry typeCode="DRIV">
                            <procedure classCode="ACT" moodCode="EVN">
                                <!-- Procedure Activity Act Template -->
                                <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.4.12"/>
                                <id root="e401f340-7be2-11db-9fe1-0800200c9a66"/>
                                <code xsi:type="CE" code="97802" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.12"
                                    displayName="Medical nutrition, indiv, in"
                                    codeSystemName="CPT">
```

Clearly the first entry is related to the section if you go through the contents as both are related to vital signs. This is a manual process. Is there any rule in the CDA schema that makes it crystal clear so that it can be implemented/identified  in an automated way generally as a program?

Comment: Don't know for sure, but isn't there a back-link / reference between CDA Level-2 and CDA Level-3, which is set within the content? The encoded values in `<entry>` point to *their* related target... (foggy memories :-D)

Comment: Thanks for replying. Forgive my ignorance but what relevance is CDA Level-2 and CDA Level-3 is in this context? Shouldn't this back-link reference be in the CDA rimm specification ideally? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, to long ago... Would have to re-read the specs and there's no time for this at the moment. Good luck anyway!

Comment: From you question - it is not obvious if you are attempting to parse or create CDA content or interrogate the implementation guide model; it sounds like the last of these options;  in other words you are given a template snippet and required to put it into the correct section per an implementation guide, is that correct ?

Comment: Somewhat yes for the parsing and implementation guide model. This is just an example. There are multiple broken sections and I have to figure out smartly which two parts to join to make a complete section. Problem is after joining some sections are still validated as a CDA document. So one section part are sometimes joined by two end parts of the section and still come out valid. So I was thinking if there could be a back-link reference between the section and upcoming entry so a semantic solution can be found. Makes sense?

Answer (score 2):

The entries that belong to the section should be enclosed in between the two section tags. So for the Vital Signs Section you show, it will have additional fields below the portion you provide and then the entries and the section ends with a closing section tag.

Comment: Many sections of different documents are broken in two parts. The question is how to join the parts of the section and have a whole section. Vital signs example seems straight forward when you look at them. The second entry in the question belongs to procedure section but there is no way to determine there relationship. There has to be a generic solution to a back-link reference of entry to section to solve this issue. Make sense?

Comment: Hi shujaat. Perhaps I still don't understand the problem you are attempting to solve. If you are presented with entries as in the example above without context and you are trying to determine what sections of a C-CDA document you should put them in, then there is not a definitive answer as to where they belong. As you identify, some are more straight forward than others. The Vital Signs organizer clearly goes in the Vital Signs Section, but the Procedure Activity Act that you provide above could go in either version of the Procedures Section. Entries required or Entries Optional.

Comment: There is another possibility that is covered in the C-CDA implementation guide as well. That is when you have either Intervention Act Entries or Planned Intervention Act Entries. Those would roll up into an Interventions Section. In these later examples, the Procedure Activity Act would be nested inside the Intervention Act Entry, which means you would need to have that entry or information about it in order to put this Procedure Activity Act in the Interventions Section.

Comment: If you wanted, it is also possible to put entries in other places. Most templates are open and therefore it is possible to add content to the templates. You could put the Procedure Activity Act in other sections and still have a valid document. The question is whether there is a valid reason for it to be aligned with the data in that section. If there is a relationship, then it could be a valid use case.

Comment: If you are trying to build out the processing for this across all the entries you have, you would likely take the entries and create your own mapping to the Sections you will put them in. For entries that have multiple possibilities, you will need some sort of additional qualifier to determine which way you will choose when aligning the entry to an appropriate section.

Comment: Hi Andrew. The last comment you made is exactly what I am looking for and that is an additional qualifier/identifier to determine entry mapping to section. I am looking into template and root id of entries and sections and their relationship for this issue now. I joined the vital sign section with entry procedure and validated the document through MDHT library. The CCDA document was validated for vital signs entry and for procedure entry with vital signs section which is erroneous behavior. So some additional identifier is needed. Make sense? Thanks a lot for your input.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not a right answer on how you qualify those entries for mapping into the possible sections. It is completely possible that an entry could fit in different sections equally well. There may also be situations where you put it in one Section for one Document type and a different Section for another Document type. There's really no hard and fast rules unless you define your own.